# Does the new Android 10 gesture for BACK trigger onKeyDown?

Tags: android, android-10.0

Android 10 has added this gesture navigation where you can go back by swiping from either the left or right edge of the screen.

Will this gesture trigger [`onKeyDown()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) just like when back is pressed on the traditional navigation bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

[`onKeyDown()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) is triggered just like before. The key code will be [`KEYCODE_BACK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK) (=4).

Also, [`onKeyUp()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyUp(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) is triggered just after as one would expect. Then [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) is called.